# How to build a django query to save mixing int and str from a json var?

Tags: python, django, json, django-models

I have a JSON var like:

```
myjson = [{"name":"bla", "value":111}, {"name":"ble", "value":222}, {"name":"bli", "value":333}, {"name":"blo", "value":444}]
```

my Django model is:

```
class myTable(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    bla = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ble = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    bli = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    blo = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s, %s, %s, %s' % (self.name, self.bla, self.ble, self.bli, self.blo)
```

I want to save this row (from my views.py):

```
from myproject.models import myTable
n = "lalala"
query = myTable(name="lalala", bla=111, ble=222, bli=333, blo=444)
query.save()
```

I don't know how to build the query iterating the JSON.

If I build an string:

```
#>>> q="lalala"
#>>> myzonesstring = 'name="'+q+'", '
#>>> for m in myjson: 
#...     myzonesstring += str(m["name"])+'='+str(m["value"])+', ' ... 
#>>> myzonesstring 'name="lalala", bla=111, ble=222, bli=333, blo=444, '
#>>> myzonesstring[:-2] 'name="lalala", bla=111, ble=222, bli=333, blo=444'
#>>> query = myTable(myzonesstring[:-2])
#>>> query.save() [. python . ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'name="lalala", bla=111, ble=222, bli=333, blo=444'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not so involved in django, but it seems to me that you do not initialize your Model correctly. From the django documenation:

> Creating objects
>
> To create a new instance of a model, just instantiate it like any other Python class:
>
> class Model(**kwargs)
>
> The keyword arguments are simply the names of the fields you’ve defined on your model.

So I would expect you'd rather have to build one dict from your json and than use this as your kwargs for the Model-**init**:

```
myjson = [{"name":"bla", "value":111}, 
          {"name":"ble", "value":222}, 
          {"name":"bli", "value":333}, 
          {"name":"blo", "value":444}]

kwargs = dict(map(lambda x: (x["name"], x["value"]), myjson))    
kwargs["name"] = "lalala"

table = myTable(**kwargs)
table.save()
```

BTW, I renamed `query` to `table`; you do not create a query, you create an object (instance of class myTable). This object then takes care of creating the query for the database when you call save()

Greetings,
Thorsten

Comment: Thanks a lot Thorsten. Probably build one dict is the best option. I also need to add the name = models.TextField(max_length=2000) that is not in the json. I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

@Thorsten: Yes it worked out for me. Here the snippet (directly from my views.py)

```
mydict = dict(map(lambda x: (x["name"], x["value"]), myjson)) 
mydict["query"]="lalala" 
m = Queries(**mydict) 
m.save()
```

It get save correctly in the ddbb. Thanks again

Comment: Then please mark my answer as solution. These are the sweets we're all here for ;-)